# Java - Splitting String Array with a Comma

Tags: java, arrays, split

I'm looking to split a sentence into an array of words separated by a comma in Java.

That is, I want a sentence like:

> "The dog jumped"
>
> "high over the"

to become

> "The,dog,jumped"
>
> "high,over,the"

I can't seem to get it to pick up the space and insert with a comma using the .split(",") method but that doesn't appear to work, the result is still the original. Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: simply googling would've solved this

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way would be to use [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), replacing spaces with `,`:

```
String s = "The dog jumped";
String sWithComma = s.replaceAll(" ", ",");
```

If you want to allow for cases more complicated than the sample you posted (multiple spaces, tabs etc.), you should use [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12128681/829571).

Comment: I would advise using `"\\s+"` instead of `" "` to catch tabs and multiple spaces as well.

Comment: @amit Fair point - I assumed from the question that the input would be always well formed. Have added link to the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using regex for one or more space and replacing it with "," like this-

```
"The dog jumped".replaceAll("\\s+", ",")
```

Answer (score -1):

Many ways to do this. I would look at using strtok for a task like this, or maybe the apache commons StringUtils package, or replaceAll. I won't give you the exact code,because this smells like an assignment :)